# How can I create a 'Click Event' on Image object in GTK3 and Python 2.7

Tags: image, python-2.7, events, onclick, gtk3

I am creating a program using Python 2.7 and GTK3+ with Glade under Linux. I have an Image object and want to run a method when the image is clicked.
Here is the object

```
<object class="GtkImage" id="imageHiResVisual">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Click here to switch between British Isles Image and Ireland</property>
    <property name="hexpand">True</property>
    <property name="vexpand">True</property>
    <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
    <signal name="button-press-event" handler="on_imageHiResVisual_button_press_event" swapped="no"/>
</object>
```

and the event handler

```
def on_imageHiResVisual_button_press_event(self, widget, data=None):
    print "I am clicked!"
```

I cannot find any event other than the "button-press-event" which might work.
I have some buttons which work fine when clicked, why does this method not work when I click the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Gtk.Image` is just a passive component, it doesn't react to button clicks. The simplest thing to do is to put it inside a `Gtk.EventBox` and react to clicks on the event box.

Comment: No need to add "SOLVED" to the title; instead, click the green checkmark. That gives both of us a reward.

Comment: Thanks for that, i did read the tutorial, but obviously missed that essential piece if information. 
I did try to votu you up, but im an not allowed to vote yet.